# sscanf returns 1 despite the line not matching the search pattern

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I need to read certain parameters from a file. My problem is to scan the lines of the file to find the parameters. The text file is structured in lines like:

```
character *\n
```

So each line has to have the pattern `(space or tab)character[space or tab][char][space or tab]\n`.

Spaces or tabs at the beginning are optional. I tried to do it with

```
char val;
if(sscanf(buf, "%*[ \t]character%*[ \t]%c%*[ \t]\n",&val)==1||sscanf(buf, "character%*[ \t]%c%*[ \t]\n",&val)==1){
    printf("%c in %i\n", val,line);
}else{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error while reading line %i\n",line);
}
```

buf contains the current line.

My problem is, in lines like `character \n` my program does not print an error. Instead it saves `'\n'` in `val`. I do not understand this behavior, because this line does not match my search pattern.

What is wrong with my code?

My understanding of my

Comment: `20` is two `char`s, not one. And `\n` is a `char` as well. Note: `\n` is the format string instructs `sscanf` to scan *any* number of whitespace chacters, including none, *until* the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: `if(sscanf(buf, " character %c", &val)==1){`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Does the space include tabs? My program should print the error message if any other character or string or integer is behind the right character, thats why I tried to code my searchpattern like this. As far as I know, your code ignores any characters after the right character and does not print the error in this case.

Comment: "_Does the space include tabs?_" -- Yes. In fact, it includes all the whitespace characters which are `' '`, `'\f'`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\t'` and `'\v'`.

Comment: @JWH see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/zxxP7l)

Comment: BTW, your post seems incomplete judging by the last sentence: "_My understanding of my_"

Comment: What would you want the output to be if there were more than one space or tab?

Comment: Perhaps using `%n` might help

Comment: the output should only be the one char after `character`. If there are more than one chars, it should print an error. If there is no char (`' '`, `\t`, and `\n` not included) it should print an error.

Comment: I was asking whether the error should be printed if there were more than 1 or less than 1 spaces or tabs *between* data, eg: `character ​ *\n` (Note the *two* spaces between 'character' and '*')

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry. There should not be an error if more than one space and/or tab divides those two. There has to be at least one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand this behavior, because this line does not match my search pattern.

The `*scanf` functions do not check the pattern first and then, if it matches, fill in the values. They check one character at a time, and indicate how many of the fields in the format string they were able to use.

Unfortunately, in your case, `%c` can certainly match `'\n'`. The subsequent `%*[ \t]` fails, as would the subsequent `\n`, but since those aren't stored anywhere, they don't affect `sscanf`'s return value, so you can't tell from the result whether there was any error.

The simplest way to solve this might be to not use `*scanf` functions at all. Your input format is easily described using a custom routine, but not so easily with a format string.